# How to use @RequestMapping headers?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am studying springmvc.  When I use `@RequestMapping(value="/helloWorld", headers = "content-type=text/*")` and connect to `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC_10100/helloWorld`, the following is output in the console:

> WARN 
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound
>   - No matching handler method found for servlet request: path `'/helloWorld'`,
>   method `'GET'`, parameters
>   `map[[empty]]`

My code is:

```java
@Controller
public class HelloWordController {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWordController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/helloWorld", headers = "content-type=text/*")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        logger.debug("jin ru le");
        logger.info("The helloWorld() method is use");
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();
        view.setViewName("/helloworld");
        return view;
    }
}
```

web.xml is

```xml
<servlet>
    <description>This is Spring MVC DispatcherServlet</description>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC DispatchServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>SpringContext</description>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:springmvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC DispatchServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its most likely the case that /helloworld is not inside the path configured for your dispatcher servlet

e.g. If i have a servlet configured like so:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>BMA</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BMA</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/bma/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And i have a controller configured like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/planner/plan/{planId}/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deletePlanConfirm(HttpServletRequest request,  
       @PathVariable("planId")   Long planId)   {}
```

Then the request in browsder would be:

```
http://localhost:8080/bma/planner/plan/1223/delete
```

Edit:
**Also if you have content-type header narrowing on your handler, make sure that content-type haeder is sent in your request.**

Comment: I want to try  @RequestMapping in headers parameter,but is not success

Comment: @EdwardLau Thats because the Content-Type header is missing in the request, When you do a get from a browser, the browser does not send a content-type header, If done via ajax, you can set the header explicitly. I've edited my answer

Comment: You most likely don't want to use the "Content-Type" header in this situation, but an "Accept" header. Specifying Content-Type for GET requests makes no sense, since you don't have an entity-body, and thus no content to specify the type of.

Answer (score 1):

In the below annotation remove the headers:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/helloWorld", headers = "content-type=text/*")
```

to:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/helloWorld",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

or to:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/helloWorld")
```

should make it work.