# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI.... in DispatcherServlet with name 'main'

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am newly working on spring mvc,I am using "spring in practice" book and this is the first mvc programme which I tried and I am getting the below error

```
 WARN  PageNotFound:1101 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MVC_BOOK_Annotation/main/list.do] in DispatcherServlet with name 'main'
```

below is my code

### RosterController

```
package com.web;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.model.Member;

@Controller
public final class RosterController {
    private List<Member> members = new ArrayList<Member>();

    public RosterController() {
        members.add(new Member("John", "Lennon"));
        members.add(new Member("Paul", "McCartney"));
        members.add(new Member("George", "Harrison"));
        members.add(new Member("Ringo", "Starr"));
    }

    @RequestMapping
    public void list(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(members);
    }

    @RequestMapping
    public void member(@RequestParam("id") Integer id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(members.get(id));
    }
}
```

### Member.java

```
package com.model;

public class Member {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Member() {
    }

    public Member(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

### main-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <bean class="com.web.RosterController" name="/roster/"></bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

### web.xml

```
<web-app id="AppName" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/main/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

### list.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <c:forEach var="member" items="${memberList}" varStatus="status">
            <li><a href="member.do?id=${status.index}"> <c:out
                        value="${member}"></c:out>
            </a></li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

### member.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Member: ${member}</h1>
    <p>
        <a href="list.do">Back</a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

the above code is almost similar to the book code but still I am unable to find where is the mistake.I attached an @RequestMapping attribute to the list() and member() methods,This identifies them as request-servicing methods.Below is my project structure screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `*` after `/roster/` in your bean definition.

Try following setting:

```
<bean class="com.web.RosterController" name="/roster/*"></bean>
```

instead of

```
<bean class="com.web.RosterController" name="/roster/"></bean>
```

And access `/MVC_BOOK_Annotation/main/roster/list.do`

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, OP uses [BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping.html) which is one of the default HandlerMappings.

Comment: In the above program I did two mistake one is <bean class="com.web.RosterController" name="/roster/"></bean> where I missed * and another one is my url should be like this /MVC_BOOK_Annotation/main/roster/list[.*] instead of /MVC_BOOK_Annotation/main/list[.*].

Answer (score 2):

You are using `@RequestMapping` without `value`-parameter, that way requests to your path wont get catched.

[How to use @requestMapping headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332150/how-to-use-requestmapping-headers)

I highly recommend reading [all of this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), without that knowledge you wont get far ...

Comment: Thanks. You helped me get out of hours of frustration. I'll read what you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `annotations` to search your `controller`. You should be using the below code.

```
context:component-scan base-package="com"
```

tag in your `Main-servlet`

Comment: we may did any mistake in configuration check it

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to add the below mapping:

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <!-- <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> -->

<!-- <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/META-INF/public-web-resources/"/> -->

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory  -->
     <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>  

    <!-- View Handler -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
<beans:property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
<beans:property name="mediaTypes">
<beans:map>
<beans:entry key="xml" value="text/xml"/>
<beans:entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
<beans:entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
<beans:entry key="less" value="text/html"/>
</beans:map>
</beans:property>
<beans:property name="viewResolvers">
<beans:list>
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
<beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/> 
</beans:bean> 
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
<beans:property name="prefix" value="/"/> 
</beans:bean> 
 </beans:list> 
 </beans:property> 
 </beans:bean>
```